# Dummy output - No Sound Card Detected - VAIO VGN-FS640/W on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, sound, 16.04, alsa, vaio

I know that this question has a lot of answers but, none of them work for me. I have been trying for hours to resolve this problem but nothing.

The last thing I have tried is the following: Purge alsa-base and pulseaudio

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

And now when I try to force reload alsa it shows me the following:

```
paul@paul-VGN-FS640W:~$ sudo alsa force-reload
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).
```

Can someone PLEASE HELP ME, I honestly have run out of patience and options.

My audio card is Realtek High Definition Audio